# Made a mistake and deleted just some of the files in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ how do I restore the files?

Tags: 16.04, unity, unity-control-center

I was going some testing and decided to delete some library files in

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

(Horrible idea I know) The side effect of deleting those files is that I am unable to open the gnome or unity control center for Ubuntu. 
When I open the control center by running unity-control-center -v

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: sqlite3_errstr
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-1/panels/libinfo.so
** (unity-control-center:9666): DEBUG: Enabling debugging
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: sqlite3_errstr
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-control-center-1/panels/libinfo.so
```

I have everywhere for this error and tried reinstalling many many diffrent libs but none seem to work.
This is different from other questions because the libraries can be restored by installing the right packages
Using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: This might get kinda hard because there are thousands of files usually in that folder

Comment: With regard to your edit, no it's not different from the question linked to above, since that question has an answer that involves reinstalling the right packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options here:

1. You should try to fix this with `debsums`. You can find missed files with it and reinstall their packages with the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install debsums
   sudo debsums_init
   sudo debsums --changed --silent
   ```

   then reinstall mentioned packages manually with

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
2. Or try to find all packages, which have files in */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/* with `dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` or combined with re-installation

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall `dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
   | sed 's/,/ /g' | head -c-28`
   ```