# virtualbox suddenly stopped working, Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: 14.04, server, virtualbox, segmentation-fault

I was working with virtualbox on ubuntu 14.04 suddenly it closed and didn't start afterward. when I tried to load it from terminal it showed me `LibQtCore.so.4 file too short`, which I've fixed it by reinstalling all needed libraries.

but after rebuilding libraries when I try to open virtualbox from terminal I get :

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And there is no clue what should I do to fix this. 
Also my vlc and clementine players has the same status.

what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Just to be sure, do a [memtest](https://www.memtest86.com/) to see if your RAM is failing.

Comment: @fkraiem sure i will, but i don't it's ram problem. I have 32 gig ram. and never had a problem with it.

Comment: Have you tried purging and reinstalling VirtualBox?

Comment: @NerdOfCode I've just tried, I removed it entirly and result was the same.

Comment: @fkraiem I've done memetest and there was nothing wrong.

Comment: It seems you ignore message about Qt. Try to reinstall corresponding package with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libqtcore4`. You can try to scan your system with `debsums` like in my [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/987824/66509).

Comment: @N0rbert I've reinstalled qt libraries and followed your approach and the other answer approach too, but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with virtualbox myself.

I was running on the latest virtualbox `5.2.6` on my `ubuntu 16.04`.

I did a `purge` and `autoremove` all of its libraries+virtualbox.

Installed previous stable version - `5.1.32` and its extensions.

Everything worked fine ever since.

Try to run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-5.2.x
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1
```

if you can't install it from `commandline` then go to their website:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Download the 5.1.32 for ubuntu 14.04/16.04 install the `.deb` file package by:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.32-120294_Ubuntu_xenial_amd64.deb
```

Let us know how it goes.