# How to fix synaptic: error while loading shared libraries: libxapian.so.30: cannot open shared?

Tags: 20.04, package-management, dpkg

**System Info:
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64bit, gnome 3.36.8, windowing system X11
RAM 15GB, SSD 500GB, Intel i5**

Just installed synaptic but could not run it.
I am not sure why it kept looking for *libxapian.so.30* when there is *libxapian.so* in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder. Also why *libxapian.so* is appended with *".30"*.

Kindly help me fix it. I am posting this for synaptic but this is happening with almost all newly installed apps.

````
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libept1.6.0
Suggested packages:
  dwww menu deborphan
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libept1.6.0 synaptic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 701 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,663 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libept1.6.0 amd64 1.1+nmu3ubuntu3 [79.6 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 synaptic amd64 0.84.6ubuntu5 [622 kB]
Fetched 701 kB in 4s (192 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package libept1.6.0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 388385 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libept1.6.0_1.1+nmu3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libept1.6.0:amd64 (1.1+nmu3ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package synaptic.
Preparing to unpack .../synaptic_0.84.6ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking synaptic (0.84.6ubuntu5) ...
Setting up libept1.6.0:amd64 (1.1+nmu3ubuntu3) ...
Setting up synaptic (0.84.6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
user@host:~$ synaptic
synaptic: error while loading shared libraries: libxapian.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
user@host:~$ ^C
user@host:~$ sudo updatedb
user@host:~$ locate libxapian.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxapian.so
user@host:~$ ```

aa
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinstall the [proper library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libxapian.so) from official Ubuntu package by using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxapian30 libxapian-dev
```

and then retry running Synaptic.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it fixed the issue. Actually I accidentally removed /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  folder. to resolve this I copied same folder from liveusb drive. probably because of this libraries are missing.
Is there any way to list all missing library and than download them?

Comment: You have to try the following answer - https://askubuntu.com/a/987824/66509 .